# Restriction Functions and Their Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f_n : S \rightarrow R$ are functions that converge uniformly to $f : S \rightarrow R$. Suppose that $A ⊂ S$.
Show that the sequence of restrictions {$ f_n|A$} converges uniformly to $f |A$

Comment: What have you tried? What's your sticking point? Is it the definition of uniform continuity that's tripping you up? When you ask questions, please give some idea of what you've tried so that answerers don't tell you what you already know.

Answer (score 2):

Really we haven't  much  to write just

$$0\leq\sup_{x\in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in S}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\longrightarrow0$$